# Why does storing a result from the pidof command result in 2 PID's but the command on its own results in the 1 PID?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, scripting

This is on my Pi 4.

When I run the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
strScriptName=$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)

pidof -x "$strScriptName" | tr " " "\n"

pid=$(pidof -x "$strScriptName" | tr " " "\n")
echo $pid

pidof -x "$strScriptName" | tr " " "\n"
```

I get something like this:

```
12703
12707 12703
12703
```

Please explain why using the  pidof command on its own results in single PID but storing the result in a varible results in 2 PIDs? (Taking the tr command off results in a single PID so I'm guessing it is something to do with piping to another command but why I get a different result when storing the result in a varible is bugging me)

Comment: 12703 is the bash process running the script. 12707 is the bash subshell spawned by `$(...)` -- you can verify this by adding `echo $$ $BASHPID;` into the command substitution.

Comment: If you take off the pipe for the tr command and I only get a single PID for each of them. Is this becase something inside $(...) gets it's own sub process?

Answer (score 1):

That's very likely because the command substitution starts a subshell, which in Bash is an actual copy of the shell process. So you'd have two shells that both show up as running processes with the command line `bash scriptname.sh`, so if `pidof` looks for that, there are two.

(The pipeline actually starts subshells too for the parts of the pipeline, but you might not see them as the shell executes the actual commands pretty quickly.)

But, if what you want is the PID of the script, there's no need to use `pidof` or such, the PID is available as `$$`. Similarly, you can get the name the script was called by from `$0`.